meta-llama/Llama-2-13b-hf torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 50.00 MiB. GPU
I am trying load Llama-2-13b on multiple GPU's but isn't loading, i have 3 GPU's 24.169 GB each , but unable to load, i have tried using cuda or device_map ='auto'
This is my current code. When I try nvidia-smi in terminal, the GPU is always at 0%.When i remove split options then it works, but then it runs on CPU.
here's below my try:
import json
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM,pipeline

device_map = 'auto'

# Load the tokenizer and model from Hugging Face hub
access_token = token
model = "meta-llama/Llama-2-13b-hf"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model,token=access_token)
documents = """
{
    "abovegradefinishedarea": 1215.0,
    "bathroomsfull": 2,
    "bathroomstotalinteger": 2,
    "bedroomstotal": 3,
    "yearbuilt": 1909,
    "city": "Minneapolis",
    "closedate": "2022-09-23",
}
"""

question = 'what is the name of the city?\n'
input = f"""
        <<SYS>>
        Only respond with "Not in the text." if the information needed to answer the question is not contained in the document. \n
        Answer the question using only the information from the provided information below. \n
        Ensure that the questions are answered fully and effectively. \n
        Respond in short and concise yet fully formulated sentences, being precise and accurate
        <</SYS>>
        [INST]
        User:{question}
        [/INST]\
        [INST]
        User:{documents}
        [/INST]\n

        Assistant:
    """
llama_pipeline = pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    device_map = 'auto',
    temperature=0.1,
)


sequences = llama_pipeline(
    input,
    do_sample=True,
    top_k=50,
    num_return_sequences=2,
    max_new_tokens=2048,
    return_full_text=False,
    temperature=0.1,
)
print("Chatbot:", sequences[0]['generated_text'])

